# When defining scalatest within sbt libraryDependencies, why does everyone use the "test" configuration?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

beginner trying to learn Scala and sbt here. Also, very little Maven experience. So, possibly a stupid question.

When defining libraryDependencies within build.sbt, often I see examples such as:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.6" % "test"
```

This follows the format:

```
libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % version % configuration
```

In this scenario, why are we using `test` for the `configuration` field? How would I know that other than copy/pasting examples from the web?

Any insight could help a lot for me better understand how to specify library dependencies in general within my projects. Also, any references to material that I could use to dive deeper into the subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find useful the following links:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#ivy-configurations

> You put a dependency in a configuration by selecting one or more of
>   its configurations to map to one or more of your project’s
>   configurations. The most common case is to have one of your
>   configurations A use a dependency’s configuration B. The mapping for
>   this looks like "A->B". To apply this mapping to a dependency, add it
>   to the end of your dependency definition:
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.3" %
>   "test->compile"
>
> This says that your project’s "test" configuration uses ScalaTest’s
>   "compile" configuration. Most projects published to Maven repositories will use the "compile" configuration.
>
> A configuration without a mapping (no "->") is mapped to "default" or
>   "compile". The -> is only needed when mapping to a different
>   configuration than those.

https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/tutorial/conf.html

> **build->api** : here we tell Ivy that our **build** configuration depends on the **api** configuration of the dependency
>
> **noexternaljar->homemade-impl** : here we tell Ivy that our **noexternaljar** configuration depends on the **homemade-impl** configuration
>   of the dependency.
>
> **withexternaljar->cc-impl** : here we tell Ivy that our **withexternaljar** configuration depends on the **cc-impl** configuration of
>   the dependency

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html

> lazy val scalacheck = "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.4"
>
> libraryDependencies += scalacheck % Test
>
> Test is the configuration and means that ScalaCheck will only be on
>   the test classpath and it isn’t needed by the main sources. This is
>   generally good practice for libraries because your users don’t
>   typically need your test dependencies to use your library.